# Show PDF content using GWT

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

How I can show .pdf files content in browser using GXT or GWT Libraries.

Answer (score 2):

1) Web browsers can embed PDF documents handily, this is probably the most practical solution (use standard html windows in your GWT application that display the PDF, and make sure the PDF is accessible from the web).  A GWT Child frame can effectively embed a pdf using native browser capabilities, just make sure you encode the content correctly in the header.

2) If you want to do some GWT/java/pdf wizardry, you can use iText's PDF reader/writer interface to customize the type of PDF data you want to display.

The ultimate answer depends on wether you want to embed a WHOLE pdf, or simply extract/create PDF contents as part of your web app.

Comment: thanks for answer. I have a grid, which displays Title of documents. When user click's on Title, content of approriate PDF file must appear on page.